# How do I query "Timestamp() or Date()" with MongoTemplate to MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I use MongoTemplate to handle MongoDB

I want update documents' column to current time

In Mongodb command-line client, it will work with

db.collectionName.update({_id:1}, {timeCol: new Timestamp()});
or
db.collectionName.update({_id:1}, {timeCol: new Date()});

But I don't know how I do that by using mongoTemplate.

Update update;
update.set("timeCol", "new Timestamp()"); // of course, it doesn't work

Plz help me

Answer (score 1):

Update Collection like this from Spring-data-mongodb 1.6 version, this will use MongoDb current Date

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(1));

Update update = new Update();
update.currentDate("timeCol")

mongoOperations.updateFirst(query, update, "collectionName");
```

If you want Timestamp use update.currentTimestamp(key); instead of update.currentDate(key)

Comment: @Minsu did this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Build current timestamp as

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(currentDate.getTime());
```

Then update collection like this :

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(1));

Update update = new Update();
update.set("timeCol", timeStamp);

mongoOperations.updateFirst(query, update, "collectionName");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I used that, but it's not DB's timestamp but WAS's timestamp.
I want to update to accurate timestamp of DB server